# android studio not generating iml file?

Tags: java, android, file, android-studio, project

hi i am android developer and i am getting some problem , usually i do not care about .iml file in project folder but my senior said me that i do not have .iml file in my project . i do not know what the usage of .iml file and how to use it .

but the main thing is that android studio is not generating .iml file for my any project . for example in other developers project , if project name is apple than there would be apple.iml in project folder but it is not happening in my case . i have also updated my Android Studio in hope that it would get fix but it didn't .

well , please help me how to fix this problem and also tell me what is the usage of .iml file in android projects

Answer (score 2):

> IML is a module file created by IntelliJ IDEA, an IDE used to develop Java applications. It stores information about a development module, which may be a Java, Plugin, Android, or Maven component; saves the module paths, dependencies, and other settings.

In case if an .iml file is not generated on your project, there
are two ways to do that,

First:

1. Go to Android Studio and open your project.
2. Go to Files
3. Select Sync Project with Gradle Files

Second:

1. Close your Android Studio
2. Go to your root project directory
3. Delete the .idea folder. If not visible you can check the hidden folders
4. Import the same project again.

This should re-generate your .iml files

Comment: thank you for trying to give an answer bu i already i have tried this approach and unfortunately this does not work

Comment: Where exactly are you checking these .iml files? Are you seeing any error while building the project?

Comment: Also try doing to Files-> Invalidate caches and Restart

Comment: Deep Lathiya , i am not getting any error and i have also tried invalidate caches and restart but does not work

Comment: Then your IDE must be generating those files, you're not looking in the right direction.

Comment: try to follow these steps...and also not working

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle > check generate *.iml files for modules imported from gradle. After change settings, resync project, iml files will be generated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**To generate a new `.iml` file**

1. You have to delete all the folder starting with the dot(.) like `.idea`, `.dart_tool` and `pubspec.lock` file
2. The project folder name should be all lowercase, with underscores to separate words, `just_like_this`.
3. Open your project in the Android Studio from terminal run this command `flutter create --platforms=android .`
4. This will generate `just_like_this.iml` file for you. If your package name is different then delete a new directory generated in your project file if needed.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem:

1. Close your IDE
2. Delete the .idea folder
3. Start your IDE again.
   Your .idea folder will be generated again, including the iml file.

> IML file stands for IntelliJ IDEA Module, created by an integrated
> development environment (IDE). It’s a popular contact management
> software used to develop java applications and games. IML file stores
> information concerning development modules like an android, plugin,
> java, or maven component of a java application. It stores modules,
> paths, types, dependencies, and order settings. Additionally, it
> stores a module-level setting for larger development projects while
> using XML formatting. In case you delete a module IML file, you can
> regenerate the file by rebuilding your project, reimporting your
> project, or opening and closing IDE. IML file is referenced and
> generated within IDEs.